# SQL to improve performance

Tags: sql, performance, date, time, oledb

Here is my problem, i have a table ( in an excel sheet and connecting it using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) with various columns that tracks the in/out card swipes from the RF card reader in the following format...

```
Date, Time Occurred, Employee Number, Employee Name, Location
2013-12-20, 11:10:23 AM, 123456, Tester, Door001 IN
2013-12-20, 11:21:44 AM, 123456, Tester, Door002 OUT
2013-12-20, 12:00:12 AM, 123456, Tester, Door001 IN
2013-12-20, 01:00:23 PM, 123456, Tester, Door002 IN
2013-12-20, 03:40:43 PM, 123456, Tester, Door001 OUT
2013-12-20, 05:00:58 PM, 123456, Tester, Door004 IN
2013-12-20, 05:50:02 PM, 123456, Tester, Door001 OUT
2013-12-20, 05:10:00 PM, 123456, Tester, Door002 OUT
2013-12-20, 11:00:01 PM, 123456, Tester, Door001 IN
2013-12-20, 09:10:23 AM, 789012, Developer, Door001 IN
2013-12-20, 10:00:44 AM, 789012, Developer, Door002 OUT
2013-12-20, 10:01:12 AM, 789012, Developer, Door003 IN
2013-12-20, 11:00:23 AM, 789012, Developer, Door004 OUT
2013-12-20, 02:40:43 PM, 789012, Developer, Door005 IN
2013-12-20, 01:00:58 PM, 789012, Developer, Door006 OUT
2013-12-20, 06:50:02 PM, 789012, Developer, Door007 IN
2013-12-20, 08:00:00 PM, 789012, Developer, Door008 IN
2013-12-20, 09:00:01 PM, 789012, Developer, Door009 OUT
```

I want the output in the following format:

```
Date,Employee Id, Employee Name, First In Time, First In Door Name, Last out time, Last Out Door Name
2013-12-20, 123456, Tester, 12:00:12 AM, Door001 IN, 11:00:01 PM, Door001 OUT
2013-12-20, 789012, Developer, 9:10:23 AM, Door001 IN, 9:00:01 PM, Door009 OUT
```

Note that the First In Time and Last out time come from the same column in raw data and similarly First In Door Name and Last Out Door Name

I have this working but not performant i think...
Currently, i am writing an SQL that fetched the distinct Employee Id from the source table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Employee Number] 
FROM [Sheet1$]
```

Then i fire two separate queries to get the first in time and first in door name store in the excel and fire another query for last out and last out door.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [sheet1$] 
WHERE  ( [employee number] = '" & Trim(rst.Fields(0).Value) & "' ) 
       AND ( location LIKE '% IN%' ) 
       AND ( 
[sheet1$].[time occurred] >= '" & Format(startTime, "hh:mm:ss") & "' 
AND [sheet1$].[time occurred] <= '" & Format(endTime, "hh:mm:ss") & "' ) 
ORDER  BY [time occurred] ASC 


SELECT * 
FROM   [sheet1$] 
WHERE  ( [employee number] = '" & Trim(rst.Fields(0).Value) & "' ) 
       AND ( location LIKE '% OUT%' ) 
       AND ( 
[sheet1$].[time occurred] >= '" & Format(startTime, "hh:mm:ss") & "' 
AND [sheet1$].[time occurred] <= '" & Format(endTime, "hh:mm:ss") & "' ) 
ORDER  BY [time occurred] DESC
```

For a given time filter, To get the 'first in time/door' i use ASC sorting and for 'Last out/door', i use ASC/DESC sorting and pick up the first rows from the results . The problem is on a typical day, I can see about 10000 unique employee in the building and thus firing two queries for each employee number (thus 20000 queries) takes hell of a time. Also to add to the misery, I am writing this is a VB macro, so add the loops, if blocks conditions etc for the processing and it makes it a bit painfully slow to get the data.

Just thinking if I can avoid these 20000 queries and somehow have just one query for all these fetches, i think it would be must faster. Any thoughts how i could reduce the logic by having it all in one SQL as an output rather than 20000 queries ? 
FYI , i tried using JOINs but somehow i am not getting it :(

Comment: Which database engine is being used to process the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query with Dynamic columns:

```
SELECT E.EMP_ID, 
(SELECT MIN(SWIPE_TIME) FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND DOOR_NAME LIKE '%IN%') AS TIME_IN, 
(SELECT DOOR_NAME FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND SWIPE_TIME = TIME_IN) AS DOOR_IN,
(SELECT MAX(SWIPE_TIME) FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND DOOR_NAME LIKE '%OUT%') AS TIME_OUT, 
(SELECT DOOR_NAME FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND SWIPE_TIME = TIME_OUT) AS DOOR_IN,
FROM SWIPES E
GROUP BY E.EMP_ID;
```

Query without dynamic columns:

```
SELECT E.EMP_ID, 
(SELECT MIN(SWIPE_TIME) FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND DOOR_NAME LIKE '%IN%') AS TIME_IN, 
(SELECT DOOR_NAME FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND SWIPE_TIME = 
    (SELECT MIN(SWIPE_TIME) FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND DOOR_NAME LIKE '%IN%')
) AS DOOR_IN,
(SELECT MAX(SWIPE_TIME) FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND DOOR_NAME LIKE '%OUT%') AS TIME_OUT, 

(SELECT DOOR_NAME FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND SWIPE_TIME = 
    (SELECT MAX(SWIPE_TIME) FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND DOOR_NAME LIKE '%OUT%')

) AS DOOR_OUT
FROM SWIPES E
GROUP BY E.EMP_ID;
```

I have updated the query as per our discussion.

Comment: ok here i have two logical data to pick - 1) first in time corresponding to Location with '% IN' 2) last out time corresponding to location with '% OUT' .... how do i achieve this via your query ?

Comment: One question: is it possible for an employee to have out time lesser than in time?

Comment: Yes, imagine a situation where the admin guys want to filter the records for a specific time period say 1 PM to 2 PM, in that case you may see OUT swipe earlier than IN ( say he goes out for smoke ;) )

Comment: I have modified the query. Please check if that works. Need to change the column names and table name though.

Comment: Thanks Darshan, it at least give me some string to think on. but...i try using your query and it complains about "too few parameter"... I suspect its due to the [TIME_IN] and [TIME_OUT] columns that we created dynamically. When if replace the [TIME_IN] and [TIME_OUT] with a value while filtering for location it fires a query but complains when i use [TIME_IN] and [TIME_OUT]..... any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: Am not sure how to find it. There is no database server. I am querying MS excel by connecting it via Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. In this case how do i find the structure ?

Comment: Even I do not have any idea about Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB. Anyway, I am altering the query to remove the usage of dynamic columns. Please check if this works or not.


`SELECT E.EMP_ID, 
(SELECT MIN(SWIPE_TIME) FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND DOOR_NAME LIKE '%IN%') AS TIME_IN, 
(SELECT MAX(SWIPE_TIME) FROM SWIPES WHERE EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID AND DOOR_NAME LIKE '%OUT%') AS TIME_OUT 
FROM SWIPES E
GROUP BY E.EMP_ID;`

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear in the previous reply. It does not error for Select query for TIME_IN. It errors for the location.. so `(SELECT `Sheet1$`.`Location` FROM `Sheet1$` WHERE `Sheet1$`.`Employee Number` = E.`Employee Number` AND `Sheet1$`.`Time Occurred` = `TIME_IN`) AS [LOCATION_IN]` so it complains at this statement and likewise the `[LOCATION_OUT]` . The select query for `(SELECT MAX(`Sheet1$`.`Time Occurred`) FROM `Sheet1$` WHERE `Sheet1$`.`Employee Number` = E.`Employee Number` AND `Sheet1$`.`Location` LIKE '%OUT%') AS [TIME_OUT]` runs just fine.Apologize for d autoformat on this site

Comment: I understand the problem. To resolve this, we need to fetch the TIME_IN again while fetching DOOR_IN and DOOR_OUT. I will update the query.

Comment: Hi Darshan, thanks! that works functionally, but still it take a lot of time to execute, rightly so, since it adds two more sub selects. But at least it works in one query that satisfies by one of trhe intention to get all in one SQL. For improving the performance, I am still searching if I could get rid of the second select for filtering the location. Also can you also update your previous query ? anyone who can use your previous SQL can refer it. Many thanks ! also wondering how to mark your answer as useful ? i dont have enough reps to do it.

Comment: Sure. I will surely update the previous query. Regarding the performance improvement, yes, you are correct. The additional complexity is introduced due to query of finding the location as well as inability of excel queries to use the dynamically generated column. If we don't want location then we can simplify it. Anyway, thanks.